# Password Help (combinations/permutations)

Tags: permutations, combinations

Much appreciated if someone can tell me if I did these correctly or not;

Repetition is allowed. 26 Capital, 26 Lowercase, 10 Number, 32 Special Characters

1) **Question**: 8 Characters long, must include 1 capital, 1 number.

**Answer**: (any 8 characters) - (no caps) - (no digits) + (neither caps or digits) = $(26+26+10+32)^8 - (26+10+32)^8 - (26+26+32)^8 + (26+32)^8 = 3.237 \times 10^{15}$

2) **Question**: 8 Characters long, must include 1 capital, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 special character (**only 3 total special characters are accepted**)

**Answer**: (any 8 characters) - (no caps) - (no lowercase) - (no digits) - (no special characters) + (neither caps, lower, number, or special char) = $(26+26+10+3)^8 - (26+10+3)^8 - (26+10+3)^8 - (26+26+3)^8 - (26+26+10)^8 + (0)^8 = 5.866 \times 10^{12}$

If those answers are correct, why would question **#2** be a smaller number than **#1**?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1 is correct.

Part 2 is not because you didn't actually use the requirement that there be exactly 1-3 special characters.

Regardless, the correct answer of #2 is clearly less than that of #1: all passwords that fulfill the requirements of #2 also fulfill the requirements of #1. Thus the set of passwords for #2 is a subset of those for #1.

Inclusion-exclusion is going to get pretty ugly when you need to count 0,1,2,3,4 special characters, so split them:

(number of ways to choose 1 character out of 8) $\times$ (strings of 1 special character) $\times$ (strings of 7 characters using only capitals/lowercase/numbers, with at least 1 capital, 1 lowercase, 1 number)

$+$

(number of ways to choose 2 characters out of 8) $\times$ (strings of 2 special characters) $\times$ (strings of 6 characters using only capitals/lowercase/numbers, with at least 1 capital, 1 lowercase, 1 number)

$+$

repeat for 3 special characters.

That you can do.

Additionally, inclusion-exclusion for three sets $A,B,C$ is more complicated:
$$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$
You need to properly include *all* multi-way intersections, so "no caps nor lowercase", for example, is missing.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'm not great with this math so I apologize if my questions seem dumb - For Part 2, how come you would treat the special characters differently than the other requirements? What I mean is, how come Part 1 works but when you add the requirement of at least 1 special character it changes?

Comment: The main difference is that you *only* care about 1+ capital letter, which means your inclusion-exclusion case is easy - all passwords vs all passwords with zero capitals. When you want to trace 0, 1-3, 4+ special characters, this is not so easy.

Comment: Okay - I was told this would be correct for Part 2 - Is this another way to do it? (8*26!) (7*26) (6*10!) (5*3!) (4*65!)(3*65!)(2*65!)(1*65!) + (8*26!) (7*26) (6*10!) (5*2!) (4*65!)(3*65!)(2*65!)(1*65!) + (8*26!) (7*26) (6*10!) (5*1!) (4*65!)(3*65!)(2*65!)(1*65!)

Comment: 26! cannot possibly be correct: it's utterly huge - the number of ways to order *all* upper or lowercase letters.

Comment: Yeah, a tutor told me it was correct but doesn't look correct. Can you help me understand how to handle your solution you posted? If not that's no problem. I just don't understand what the solution of this would look like - (number of ways to choose 1 character out of 8) × (strings of 1 special character) × (strings of 7 characters using only capitals/lowercase/numbers, with at least 1 capital, 1 lowercase, 1 number)

Comment: is it like - 8C1 * 3C1 * 26C1 and so on?

Then repeat 3 times ?

Comment: Somewhat close - this is an alternate way to do it, provided you sum over **all** allowed number combinations of each type of letter. That means (1 capital, 1 lowercase, 3 number, 3 special), (1 capital, 1 lowercase, 4 number, 2 special), ... (5 capital, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 special). That is a huge stack of possibilities, which is a mess.

Comment: Additionally, the "choosing" aspect (which implies you cannot choose the same thing twice) only works for positions - letters are allowed to repeat after all. So to go for (1 capital, 2 lowercase, 3 number, 2 special), you're looking at a **multinomial** coefficient 8!/(1!*2!*3!*2!) * 26^1 * 26^2 * 10^3 * 32^2